# How to know when byte-serving is complete

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sending a linearized pdf file back to client using `Byte-serving`.

I want to perform some action after the file is entirely sent to the browser.

I'm not doing it from scratch, instead using Laravel's `file` method on Response service.

```
$fileStream = response()->file('/path/to/file.pdf');

// kind of like this:
if( isLastByteRange($fileStream) ) { // }

return $fileStream;
```

This file method is actually an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse` which doesn't really seem to expose anything useful to achieve my goal.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: How are you intending to run anything after a `return`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not attempting to run anything after return. The request is gonna keep coming to this route. I just wanna know the last byte range request that comes to this request via some sort of header maybe Idk.